# When adding a link to Visual Studio it reformats and shifts the text in my website down

Tags: html, visual-studio

I am creating my website portfolio in Visual Studio. I am adding a link to a website but when I do it "reformats" my text.

Original:

```
<article class="style">
 <span class="image">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt=""/>
 </span>
 <a href="pagename.html">
  <h2>Project Name</h2>
  <div class="content">
   <p>Project description</p>
  </div>
</a>
</article>
```

[Original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlqRs.png)
[Original format (mouse is over it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcRcO.png)

When adding a link:

```
<a href="pagename.html">
 <h2>Project Name</h2><a href="linkpage.html"></a>
 <div class="content">>
   <p>Project description</p>
```

[Format with link added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhtBw.png)
[Format with link added (mouse is over it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SOEb.png)

I hope my question makes sense. I am not a coder so hopefully it's an easy fix.
Thank you.

I have tried googling but I have no idea how to even phrase the question. I have only gotten how to add a link.